# Ionic: $state.go changes the url but view is not loaded

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, url-routing

When I try to change state programatically, the URL changes, but the view is not loaded. After refreshing the page it loads perfectly, but reloading it using `$window.location.reload(true);` seems a bit unusual.

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('WelcomeController', ['$scope', '$state',  '$window', 
     function($scope, $state, $window) {
         $scope.changePage = function() {
             $state.go('signup');
             // $window.location.reload(true);
         };
     }
]);
```

**States**

```
$stateProvider.state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
}).state('welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeController'
});
```

**signup.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Signup">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h2>Form</h2>   
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**welcome.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <a class="button" href="#/signup">Sign In</a>
        <button class="button" ng-click="changePage()">Sign In Programmatic</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

This is working just fine: `<a class="button" href="#/signup">Sign In</a>`

What might be the issue here? I'm new to ionic or angular and literally stuck here for two days. Tried googling, found that some others also had this issue, but none of those seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Provide more code, the problem does not come from what you have provided.

Comment: Added some more code, actually all of it. there is not anything else besides the app declaration and ionic default cordova codes.

Comment: Did you dependency injected `'ui.router'` into your module?

Comment: Yes. `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ksSwiper', 'ngStorage', 'lodash', 'ui.router']);`

Comment: this is one way to catch error , `myAapp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        if(toState.name == 'signup') { alert("error"); }
      });
    }]);`

Comment: Nothing happened. Put that under `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {...});`

Comment: put it below `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` initialization, then refresh and make sure you see the code in your console, then click on your button

Comment: Still nothing..

Answer (score -2):

```
 $state.go('signup')
```

should work correctly, if your template path is correct.

Or try below path format

```
templateUrl: site_url+'templates/signup.html',
```

site_url presents you website url ex- www.examlple.com

Comment: That not what I meant. I want to change state programatically, not by directly clicking the link.

Comment: check your template path is correct or not.also check browser console for any error.

Comment: Nothing in the console. White as death.

Comment: can you provide me a link for demo?

Comment: This is just a test work, so I don't have any live url's. But i'm trying to set up a codepen and will provide the link when done.

Comment: And, template path is correct, otherwise, it would not work on reload or with the direct link.